# How can I perform null-coalescing in an odata expression?

Tags: rest, null, odata

I would like to use $orderby within a query to order elements by two fields "CreationTime" and "LastModificationTime". In cases where the object has been created but not mutated, "LastModificationTime" is showing as null in the system.

So if this was SQL I would do

"ORDER BY COALESCE(LastModificationTime,CreationTime) DESC".

How can I replicate this data within an odata query? Thanks.